# How to render Javascript/dynamic content with aiohttp?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I  would like to know if it is possible to **render Javascript content from a website with the module aiohttp** in an asynchronous way.

I know it works with static content or API endpoints, but I don´t know how to handle asynchronously dynamic content.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: aiohttp doesn't render anything. It makes requests and passes along the responses. You'd be better off with a library that can run a headless browser instance such as selenium or pyppeteer.

Comment: thank you @dirn for helping me. Yes, I know them but they are slower than using a connection with a service like aiohttp, requests or HTMLSession.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [requests-html](https://github.com/psf/requests-html), which is like the `requests` library but with JavaScript rendering, CSS selectors, XPath selectors, and async support.